# SQL search user not in that user's blacklist

Tags: sql

I have a 'users' table

```
user_id|
1      | 
2      | 
3      | 
4      | 
5      |
```

and 'blocklist' table

```
blocker_id|blocked_id
1         | 3
2         | 3
```

now I want to search a user in 'users' table which is not blocked by **that user** **AND** that user is not blocked by **user**!

***(NOT BLOCK EACH OTHER)***
like this :

```
SELECT * FROM users
```

Comment: Your "like this" is a little vague ;)  Also, add a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: Sorry some of my text was not copied ! I edited it

Answer (score 2):

Try this, with `NOT IN()`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT blocked_id FROM blocklist)
```

Comment: I want to not blocked just by that user

Comment: I think it should be like this : 

`SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT blocked_id FROM blocklist WHERE blocker_id = users.user_id AND blocked_id = X )`

Comment: @MiladJVR Still a little unclear -- Add your expected results to your question and that should clear it up.

Comment: @MiladJVR Running the query above would return users who haven't blocked themselves

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer :

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT blocked_id FROM blocklist WHERE blocked_id = users.user_id AND blocker_id = X ) AND  user_id NOT IN (SELECT blocker_id FROM blocklist WHERE blocker_id = users.user_id AND blocked_id = X )
```

X is the user_id that i want to not blocker or blocked by sql results